# Back button doesn't switch to previous activity, but it exits the Android app

Tags: android

I have an app that contains 2 activities: A1 and A2. When I run the app it opens A1 activity. Then it opens A2 by pressing the button (I use startActivityForResult(intent, 0)). Then if I pressing Back it returns to A1. Everything is ok.

But if I am in A2 activity and **switching to another application** and then returning back to my app, then I'm pressing Back and the application exits instead of switching to A1 activity.
What can I do to prevent such situation?

The code that calls A2 from A1:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A2.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="A1"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="A2"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file, at least the parts that declare A1 and A2?

Comment: I updated the post with AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

In your activity over-ride the back button and do whatever handling you want..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Do whatever you want here on back button press
}
```

However in your case, if A2 is *only* getting started from A1 by startActivityFroResult() , then A1 must always remain in activity stack-trace..thus pressing back should always go back to A1.. unless a rare case when android os cleans up your A1 activity due to inactivity/high usage.

Comment: How could I preserve A1 activity in the stack when switching to another app and back?

Comment: can you post your code where you are startingActivity A2  from A1

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling either of the `this.finish();` or the `finish();` tag when you are calling the A2 via Intent?

You could also work on the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods. Without any code provided in the OP, the answer will be based on guessing a bit. Do correct if I'm wrong in guessing. :-)

Also, update the OP with some code. And, you could also read up about an [**Activity's Life Cycle**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle).

EDIT: The issue seems to be similar to this one here: [Android is killing my application whenever startactivityforresult is called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988946/450534). Again, it boils down to saving the activity state, a part of Activity Life Cycle.

Comment: I don't use finish() when calling A2. I updated the post. The code is simple.

Comment: @gflower: I have updated the post. The new link does have similarities with your issue. Give that one a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `singleInstance` to `singleTask` in your manifest. With `singleInstance`, Android will not launch any new instances into your task (i.e., activity back stack), which means that if the root Activity gets destroyed by the OS, it will not call A1's `onCreate` to recreate it.

The details are in the [Tasks and Back Stack document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) under ["Defining Launch Modes"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes).

Note that once A1 gets destroyed, you will have lost all its state, so you probably want to implement `onSaveInstanceState`, which will allow you to save a `Bundle` that will be passed to you in `onCreate`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly changing launchMode to `singleTask` or even `standard` doesn't help

Comment: In that case, I would add logging to A1's `onCreate` to see if it is getting called. Maybe also implement `onDestroy` just to add a logging message to see when it is destroyed.